# Sorting an Array of int using BubbleSort

Tags: java

Why is my printed out Array not sorted in the below code?

```
public class BubbleSort {

   public void sortArray(int[] x) {//go through the array and sort from smallest to highest
      for(int i=1; i<x.length; i++) {
         int temp=0;
         if(x[i-1] > x[i]) {
            temp = x[i-1];
            x[i-1] = x[i];
            x[i] = temp;
         }
      }
   }

   public void printArray(int[] x) {
      for(int i=0; i<x.length; i++)
        System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TestBubbleSort
      BubbleSort b = new BubbleSort();
      int[] num = {5,4,3,2,1};
      b.sortArray(num);
      b.printArray(num);   
   }
}
```

Comment: Your bubble sort implementation is not correct. It requires nested loops. Check the pseudo code of bubble sort on wikipedia for reference.

Comment: num[] is passed by call by value... when you sort the Array Copy of num get sorted.. You sholud return the Array to the Caller then need to print the new array with Print Array

Comment: @AkshayJoy Passing an array to a method does *not* create a copy. Half the methods in [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) would be useless if it were so.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort <-- Will give you the proper logic

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/arrayexamples/bubblesort.shtml

Comment: @prashant sorry but i don't see why i need a println instead of just print. Thank you all for the feedback.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need two loops to implement the Bubble Sort .

Sample code :

```
public static void bubbleSort(int[] numArray) {

    int n = numArray.length;
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {

            if (numArray[j - 1] > numArray[j]) {
                temp = numArray[j - 1];
                numArray[j - 1] = numArray[j];
                numArray[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You're only making one pass through your array! Bubble sort requires you to *keep looping* until you find that you are no longer doing any swapping; hence the running time of O(n^2).

Try this:

```
public void sortArray(int[] x) {
    boolean swapped = true;
    while (swapped) {
       swapped = false;
       for(int i=1; i<x.length; i++) {
           int temp=0;
           if(x[i-1] > x[i]) {
               temp = x[i-1];
                x[i-1] = x[i];
                x[i] = temp;
                swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Once `swapped == false` at the end of a loop, you have made a whole pass without finding any instances where `x[i-1] > x[i]` and, hence, you know the array is sorted. Only *then* can you terminate the algorithm.

You can also replace the outer `while` loop with a for loop of `n+1` iterations, which will guarantee that the array is in order; however, the `while` loop has the advantage of early termination in a better-than-worst-case scenario.

Comment: BTW you can replace `while (swapped == true)` with `while (swapped)`

Comment: Faster then previous one ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your sort logic is wrong.  This is the pseudo-code for bubble sort:

```
for i = 1:n,
    swapped = false
    for j = n:i+1, 
        if a[j] < a[j-1], 
            swap a[j,j-1]
            swapped = true
    → invariant: a[1..i] in final position
    break if not swapped
end
```

See this [sorting web site](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/bubble-sort) for good tutorial on all the various sorting methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I just started programming, so this method of your is new for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use this method for bubble sorting

```
public static int[] bubbleSort (int[] a) {
    int n = a.length;
    int j = 0;
    boolean swap = true;
    while (swap) {
        swap = false;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j-1] > a[j]) {
                j = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = a[j];
                a[j] = j;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
        n = n - 1;
    }
    return a;
}//end bubbleSort
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the bubble sort algorithm, you need to repeat until you have nothing to swap :

```
public void sortArray(int[] x) {//go through the array and sort from smallest to highest
  for(;;) {
      boolean s = false;
      for(int i=1; i<x.length; i++) {
         int temp=0;
         if(x[i-1] > x[i]) {
            temp = x[i-1];
            x[i-1] = x[i];
            x[i] = temp;
            s = true;
         }
      }
      if (!s) return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort nested loops should be written like this:

```
int n = intArray.length;
int temp = 0;

for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
   for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){                        
       if(intArray[j-1] > intArray[j]){
            //swap the elements!
            temp = intArray[j-1];
            intArray[j-1] = intArray[j];
            intArray[j] = temp;
       }                    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void BubbleSort(int[] array){
        boolean swapped ;
        do {
            swapped = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
                if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                    int temp = array[i];
                    array[i] = array[i + 1];
                    array[i + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
            }
        }while (swapped);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bubblesort{

  public static int arr[];

  public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("Enter number of element you have in array for performing bubblesort");

    int numbofele = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    System.out.println("numer of element entered is"+ "\n" + numbofele);

    arr= new int[numbofele];

    System.out.println("Enter Elements of array");

    System.out.println("The given array is");


    for(int i=0,j=1;i<numbofele;i++,j++){

      arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(args[j]);

      System.out.println(arr[i]);

    }

    boolean swapped = false;

    System.out.println("The sorted array is");

    for(int k=0;k<numbofele-1;k++){


      for(int l=0;l+1<numbofele-k;l++){

        if(arr[l]>arr[l+1]){

          int temp = arr[l];
          arr[l]= arr[l+1];
          arr[l+1]=temp;
          swapped=true;

        } 

      }

         if(!swapped){

            for(int m=0;m<numbofele;m++){

       System.out.println(arr[m]);

    }

      return;

      }


    }

    for(int m=0;m<numbofele;m++){

       System.out.println(arr[m]);

    }


  }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just throw your source code here. Be nice and try to give a nice description to your answer, so that others will like it and upvote it. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Bubble sort algorithm is a simplest way of sorting array elements.Most of another algorithms are more efficient than bubble sort algorithm..Worst case and average case time complexity is (n^2).Let's consider how to implement bubble sort algorithm.

```
class buble_sort{
  public static void main(String a[]){

    int[] num={7,9,2,4,5,6,3};
    int i,j,tmp;

    for(i=0;i<num.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<num.length-i;j++){
            if(j==(num.length-1)){
                break;
            }
            else{
                if(num[j]>num[j+1]){
                    tmp=num[j];
                    num[j]=num[j+1];
                    num[j+1]=tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<num.length;i++){
        System.out.print(num[i]+"  ");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here we go

```
static String arrayToString(int[] array) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      stringBuilder.append(array[i]).append(",");
    }
    return stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length()-1).toString();
  }

  public static void main(String... args){
    int[] unsorted = {9,2,1,4,0};
    System.out.println("Sorting an array of Length "+unsorted.length);
    enhancedBubbleSort(unsorted);
    //dumbBubbleSort(unsorted);
    //bubbleSort(unsorted);
    //enhancedBubbleSort(unsorted);
    //enhancedBubbleSortBetterStructured(unsorted);
    System.out.println("Sorted Array: "+arrayToString(unsorted));

  }

  // this is the dumbest BubbleSort
  static int[] dumbBubbleSort(int[] array){
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length-1 ; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          // Just swap
          int temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("After "+(i+1)+" pass: "+arrayToString(array));
    }
    return array;
  }

  //this "-i" in array.length - 1-i brings some improvement.
  // Then for making our bestcase scenario better ( o(n) , we will introduce isswapped flag) that's enhanced bubble sort

  static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array){
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length-1 ; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1-i; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          int temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
      }
      System.out.println("After "+(i+1)+" pass: "+arrayToString(array));
    }
    return array;
  }

  static int[] enhancedBubbleSort(int[] array){
    int i=0;
    while (true) {
      boolean swapped = false;
      for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          int temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
          swapped =true;
        }
      }
      i++;
      System.out.println("After "+(i)+" pass: "+arrayToString(array));
      if(!swapped){
        // Last iteration (of outer loop) didnot result in any swaps. so stopping here
        break;
      }
    }
    return array;
  }

  static int[] enhancedBubbleSortBetterStructured(int[] array){
    int i=0;
    boolean swapped = true;
    while (swapped) {
      swapped = false;
      for (int j = 0; j < array.length - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
          int temp = array[j];
          array[j] = array[j + 1];
          array[j + 1] = temp;
          swapped = true;
        }
      }
      i++;
      System.out.println("After "+(i)+" pass: "+arrayToString(array));
    }
    return array;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of **bubbleSort**, and Time Complexity is O(n).

```
 int[] bubbleSort(int[] numbers) {
        if(numbers == null || numbers.length == 1) {
            return numbers;
        }

        boolean isSorted = false;

        while(!isSorted) {
            isSorted = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
                if(numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1]) {
                    int hold = numbers[i + 1];
                    numbers[i + 1] = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = hold;
                    isSorted = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return numbers;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Really not getting the [`bubble sort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort), which can be called a sinking sort more appropriately since it's actually **sinking the bigger/heavier to the bottom** as the majority of the answers presented. One of the most typicals will be

```
private static void sortZero(Comparable[] arr) {
    boolean moreSinkingRequired = true;
    while (moreSinkingRequired) {
        moreSinkingRequired = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length - 1; ++j) {
            if (less(arr, j + 1, j)) { 
                exch(arr, j, j + 1);
                moreSinkingRequired = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, you have to traverse once more than actually required to stop earlier.

But as I see it bubbling as

```
private static void sortOne(Comparable[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; ++i) {
        for (int j = arr.length - 1; j > i; --j) { // start from the bottom
            if (less(arr, j, j - 1)) {
                exch(arr, j - 1, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You have to know this method is actually better since it's tracking the *end point* for comparison by `j > i` with `[0, i-1]` already sorted.

We also can add earlier termination but it then becomes verbose as

```
private static void sortTwo(Comparable[] arr) {
    boolean moreBubbleRequired = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1 && moreBubbleRequired; ++i) {
        moreBubbleRequired = false;
        for (int j = arr.length - 1; j > i; --j) {
            if (less(arr, j, j - 1)) {
                exch(arr, j - 1, j);
                moreBubbleRequired = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

The utils used to make the process terse are

```
public static boolean less(Comparable[] arr, int i, int j) {
    return less(arr[i], arr[j]);
}

public static boolean less(Comparable a, Comparable b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) < 0;
}

public static void exch(Comparable[] arr, int i, int j) {
    Comparable t = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = t;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SortingArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {

int[] a={3,7,9,5,1,4,0,2,8,6};
int temp=0;

boolean isSwapped=true;


System.out.println(" before sorting the array: ");

for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
    System.out.print(a[i]);
}
System.out.println("");

do
{

isSwapped=false;

for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++)

{

    if(a[i]>a[i+1])

    {

        temp=a[i];

        a[i]=a[i+1];

        a[i+1]=temp;

    }



}


}while(isSwapped);


System.out.println("after sorting the array: ");

    for(int array:a)

    {

        System.out.print(array);


    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should explain what this does and how the problem is fixed in your example.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class BubbleSort {

    public void sorter(int[] arr, int x, int y){

            int temp = arr[x];
            arr[x] = arr[y];
            arr[y] = temp;

    }

    public void sorter1(String[] arr, int x, int y){

        String temp = arr[x];
        arr[x] = arr[y];
        arr[y] = temp;

    }

    public void sertedArr(int[] a, String[] b){
        for(int j = 0; j < a.length - 1; j++){
            for(int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++){
                if(a[i] > a[i + 1]){
                    sorter(a, i, i + 1);
                    sorter1(b, i, i + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
            System.out.print(b[i]);
        }
        // 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] array = {3, 7, 4, 9, 5, 6};
        String[] name = {"t", "a", "b", "m", "2", "3"};
        BubbleSort bso = new BubbleSort();
            bso.sertedArr(array, name);
    }
}
```

Comment: To sort `String` objects (since strings implement the `Comparable` interface), simply use `Comparable.compareTo(T)`. Then, analyze the returned value (0 objects are equal, positive integer if the comparing object is less than the passed argument, and negative if the comparing object is greater than the passed argument) and sort (swap) values accordingly.

The comparison uses natural order which in the case of `String` is alphabetical or (alphanumeric in this case).

Answer (score -1):

java code

```
public void bubbleSort(int[] arr){   

    boolean isSwapped = true;

    for(int i = arr.length - 1; isSwapped; i--){

        isSwapped = false;

        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){

            if(arr[j] > arr[j+1]}{
                int temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
                isSwapped = true;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Standard Bubble Sort implementation in Java:

```
//Time complexity: O(n^2)
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] arr) {

    if (arr == null || arr.length <= 1) {
        return arr;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
            if (arr[j - 1] > arr[j]) {
                arr[j] = arr[j] + arr[j - 1];
                arr[j - 1] = arr[j] - arr[j - 1];
                arr[j] = arr[j] - arr[j - 1];
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```