# Sorting array objects Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, computer-science

For this homework assignment we are to create an array that is no larger than 10 and whose elements are of type Animal (Animal is an object that we had to create). The user is prompted to enter information about the animal (name, number of arms, legs) and the information is stored into each animal object of the array.

The program is then supposed to calculate the total number of limbs, and sort the array from greatest to least based on the calculated number.

Here is the code:

```
public static void sortArray (Array [] name)
{
    // This method will take in the array and sort it based
    // on the number of limbs from greatest to least.
    int maxLimbs = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
        int limbValue = name[i].getNumberOfLimbs();
        if (limbValue > maxLimbs) {
            maxLimbs = limbValue;
            // Store the max value in the first position
            name[0] = name[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I know this is finding the maximum value and putting it in the first position, but I am struggling to get it to sort the rest of the elements. Any suggestions on how I can fix this to where it will sort through the entire array and order them from greatest to least?

Or is there already a sort method that can be used on Arrays whose elements are objects? I am new to this so I am still trying to get the grasp of some concepts. Thank you for the help.

Comment: What is the goal of this assignment ? Should you perhaps implement some sorting algorithm such as the bubble or quicksort by hand ?

Comment: The goal of the assignment is to collect data about different animals (such as name, number of arms, number of legs) and store the information into an array. Then, the program is supposed to calculate the total number of limbs for each animal (by adding the number of arms and legs) and sort the array from greatest to least on the total number of limbs. So for example, if I enter the information for a bear, hawk, and an octopus, it will sort the array to where the animal object containing the octopus first, bear second, bird third, etc. I hope this clarifies. Sorry for being unclear :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use method Arrays.sort

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

to which you should give your array and Comparator which knows how to compare two Animal objects

Or you can use

```
public static void sort(Object[] a)
```

which requires your elements' class implements Comparable interface

Comment: Okay I will try that! I am a bit confused on how the array will know what to sort for. So for instance, I want to to be sorted based on the total number of limbs, so for the second sort method, how do I know if it will sort based on that instead of sorting alphabetically based on the string name associated with each Animal object? I guess my question really is: is there a way I can tell the method to sort based on a certain characteristic?

Comment: You also might be expected to implement a sorting yourself since it is a homework assignment. In this case there are a lot of algorithms you can find on the internet, for example bubble sort http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088994/sorting-an-array-of-int-using-bubblesort

Comment: Of course, that is the Comparator object is passed for. You create your own comparator, which knows how to compare to instances of your class being sorted.

Comment: Okay cool. I am unclear on the correct syntax of this method, so would I say something like: sort(Animal [] animalList, Comparator<? T> animalList.getTotalLimbs()) ?

Where animalList is the name I am using for the array and getTotalLimbs() is the method I have for cauculating the total number of limbs.

Comment: take a look at the example here http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/

Answer (score -1):

```
    public class SortAnimals {

        public static void main(String[] args) {    

            Animals[] animals = new Animals[3];
            animals[0] = new Animals("Animal1",0,4);
            animals[1] = new Animals("Animal2",2,6);
            animals[2] = new Animals("Animal3",1,1);

            Arrays.sort(animals,Collections.reverseOrder());

            for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; i++) {
                Animals animals2 = animals[i];
                System.out.println(animals2);

            }

        }
    }

    class Animals implements Comparable<Animals>{
        private String name;
        private int hands;
        private int legs;

//getters and setters omitted for brevity

        Animals(String name, int hands, int legs){
            this.name = name;
            this.hands = hands;
            this.legs = legs;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Animals o) {       
            int totalLimbs = this.hands + this.legs;        
            return totalLimbs - (o.hands + o.legs);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Animals [name=" + name + ", hands=" + hands + ", legs=" + legs
                    + "]";
        }   
    }
```