# Coding Bubble Sort using Java

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I don't know if I did this coding correctly, but can someone confirm if my doBubbleSort method and its implementation in the main method are programmed correctly? My coding requires me to create an array of size 20 and populate it with random integers between 1 and 1000 without hard coding them. The result should display the original, unsorted list of integers; and then display each pass of the bubble sorting algorithm on a separate line. I have to repeat the program until the user chooses to quit. **I have made edits to make sure that whatever variables I use, it is declared according to ArrayLists.

An example of how I want my output to come out as is shown below (although it only shows 5 integers when I'm trying to do 20):

***Unsorted list: 68 3 298 290 1

Pass 1: 3 68 290 1 298

Pass 2: 3 68 1 290 298

Pass 3: 3 1 68 290 298

Pass 4: 1 3 68 290 298***

```
// Used to capture keyboard input
import java.util.*;

// Our class called BubbleSort
public class BubbleSort {

    // Create doBubbleSort method 
    public static void doBubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        boolean needNextPass = true;
        while (needNextPass) {
            // Array may be sorted and next pass not needed 
            needNextPass = false;
            // Swap list
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size()-1; i++) {
                if (arr.get(i) > arr.get(i+1)) {
                    int temp = arr.get(i);
                    arr.set(i, arr.get(i+1));
                    arr.set(i+1, temp);
                    printOut(i+1, arr); // using printOut method
                    needNextPass = true; // Next pass still needed
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printOut(int pass, ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        System.out.print("PASS " + pass + ": ");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size()-1; i++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(i) + ", ");
        }
        // Shows very last integer with a period
        System.out.print(list.get(list.size()-1) + "."); 
        System.out.println();
    }

    // Main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Declare and instantiate a new ArrayList object
        Scanner userChoice = new Scanner(System.in); // User input for quitting program
        String choice = ""; // Will hold user choice to quit program
        boolean inputFlag = false; // True if input is valid, false otherwise

        // Repeat program until user chooses to quit
        while (inputFlag = true) {
            System.out.print("\nWould you like to continue the program? (Y/N): ");
            choice = userChoice.nextLine();
            if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                try {
                    /* Create an array of size 20 and populate it with random integers between 1 and 1000.
                    Do not ask user for the numbers and do not hard code them */
                    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                        int integer = (int)(1000.0 * Math.random());
                        array.add(integer);
                    }
                    System.out.print("\nUNSORTED LIST: ");

                    //Display the 20 size of the unsorted ArrayList 
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.size() - 1; i++) {
                        System.out.print(array.get(i) + ", ");
                    }
                    // Shows very last integer with a period
                    System.out.print(array.get(array.size() - 1) + "."); 
                    System.out.println();
                    doBubbleSort(array);
                }

                catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("\nThere is an out of bounds error in the ArrayList.");
                }
            }
            else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
                break;
            }
            // Error message when inputting anything other than Y/N
            else { 
                System.out.println("\nERROR. Only Y, y, N, or n may be inputted.");
                System.out.println("Please try again.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it is really a duplicate, but have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088994/sorting-an-array-of-int-using-bubblesort

Comment: Try code review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with your implementation, since you seem to be newly learning this, there are a few things you should change. First of all, since you're using an int array for the doBubbleSort method, use an int array in the main method as well.

The implementation of bubblesort needs to be changed too. You should first look into its logic carefully. Going through the whole array every time is not necessary.

```
// Create doBubbleSort method 
public static void doBubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    boolean needNextPass = true;
    // Array may be sorted and next pass not needed 
    // Swap list
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (needNextPass) {
            needNextPass = false;
            for (int j = arr.length - 1; j > i; j--) {
                int temp;
                if (arr[j] < arr[j - 1]) {
                    temp = arr[j - 1];
                    arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                    needNextPass = true; // Next pass still needed
                }
            }
            printOut(i + 1, arr); // using printOut method
        }
    }
}
```

And then, printing the array.

```
private static void printOut(int pass, int[] list) {
    System.out.print("PASS " + pass + ": ");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
        System.out.print(list[i] + ", ");
    }
    // Shows very last integer with a period
    System.out.print(list[list.length - 1] + ".");
    System.out.println();
}
```

Now the main method. I've changed the input handling part for re-running the program, and used an int array as you had originally posted.

```
// Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[20]; // Declare and instantiate a new ArrayList object
    Scanner userChoice = new Scanner(System.in); // User input for quitting program
    boolean inputFlag = true; // True if input is valid, false otherwise
    String choice;

    // Repeat program until user chooses to quit
    while (inputFlag == true) {

        try {
            /* Create an array of size 20 and populate it with random integers between 1 and 1000.
             Do not ask user for the numbers and do not hard code them */
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                int integer = (int) (1000.0 * Math.random());
                array[i] = integer;
            }
            System.out.print("\nUNSORTED LIST: ");

            //Display the 20 size of the unsorted ArrayList 
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
                System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
            }
            // Shows very last integer with a period
            System.out.print(array[array.length - 1] + ".");
            System.out.println();
            doBubbleSort(array);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("\nThere is an out of bounds error in the ArrayList.");
        }

        System.out.print("\nWould you like to continue the program? (Y/N): ");
        choice = userChoice.nextLine();

        while (!(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) && !(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))) {
            // Error message when inputting anything other than Y/N
            System.out.println("\nERROR. Only Y, y, N, or n may be inputted.");
            System.out.println("Please try again.");
            choice = userChoice.nextLine();
        }

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
            inputFlag = false;
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yes, I'm still new to coding. Oopsie, I thought it would be considered "hard-coding" if I had put int[] array = new int[20]; which is why I opt to use ArrayList<Integer>... Thanks again, always learning a lot from this site.

Comment: It is hard-coding, yes! I only put that since you specifically said you need 20 elements. You can let the user input a value for the array size and then use that to initialize the array.

`int arraySize = scanner.nextInt();`
then,
`int[] array = new int[arraySize];`

Glad it helped. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You wrote too much boiler plate code for bubble sort. For bubble sort, use recursive method. I wrote for you simple bubble method, do what you want with output

```
private int[] bubbleSort(int[] arr){

    int c;
    boolean isArranged = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i < (arr.length - 1) && arr[i] > arr[i+1]){
            c = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
            arr[i+1] = c;
            isArranged = true;
        }
    }

    if (isArranged){
        return bubbleSort(arr);
    }else{
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Call this like:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int length = in.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();
    }

    Main main = new Main();

    int[] newArr = main.bubbleSort(arr);

    for (int i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(newArr[i] + " ");
    }
```

You can write ArrayList instead int array.