# Homework: Sorting Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, numbers, selection-sort

I am supposed to create an algorithm that sorts according to these steps:

> ### Method 1
>
> Select the lowest number in the list and swap with the first number.
>
> Select the lowest number in the list and swap with the second number.
>   Start checking from the second number.
>
> Select the lowest number in the list and swap with the third number.
>   Start checking from the third number.
>
> Select the lowest number in the list and swap with the fourth number.
>   Start checking from the fourth number.
>
> Repeat…until you reach the last number.

Currently, this is the code I have come up with:

```
public static void method1() {
    int low = 999;        
    int index = 0;
    int safe;
    int[] num = new int[] { 33, 22, 8, 59, 14, 47, 60, 27 };

    for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        if(low > num[i]) {
            low = num[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        safe = num[i];
        num[i] = num[index];
        low = 999;
        for(int j = (i+1); j < num.length; j++) {
            if(low > num[j]) {
                low = num[j];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(num[i] +", ");
    }
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
run:
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Why am I only getting values of 8 in the output? As this is homework, please don't tell me the answer. I would only like guidance, thanks!

## EDIT:

Code now looks like this:

```
int low = 999;        
        int index = 0;
        int safe;
        int[] num = new int[] { 33, 22, 8, 59, 14, 47, 60, 27 };

        for(int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            if(low > num[i]){
                low = num[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            safe = num[i];
            num[i] = num[index];
            low = 999;
            for(int j = (i+1); j < num.length; j++) {
                if(low > num[j]){
                    low = num[j];
                    index = j;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(num[i] +", ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
```

Which gives me an output of:

```
run:
8, 8, 8, 14, 14, 27, 27, 27, 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question. And what have you tried to debug it?

Comment: Sorry, I added it in the post. I already did this:

` for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++){ `
            safe = num[i];
            num[i] = num[index];
            low = 999;
            for(int j = (i+1); j < num.length; j++){
                if(low > num[j]){
                    low = num[j];
                    index = j;
                }                
            }
        }

Comment: I have tried debugging it and going through step by step. I made a change  that makes the output 8, 8, 8, 14, 14, 27, 27, 27. But I cannot figure out anymore why this is happening.

Comment: He _wants_ to solve it himself. Honestly this is one of the better homework-type questions I've seen here. @OP: You're not using `safe` and you're setting incorrect values in your `num[i] = num[index];` line. Focus on that.

Comment: Look carefully at when `index` is set and updated.

Comment: @Marvin I don't get how I am setting incorrect values.

Comment: @Lance In your second loop you're going over `num` and setting the value at _every index_ to `num[index]`, which is the "lowest" value you've determined in your first loop.

Comment: @KevinO I added this:  
for(int j = (i+1); j < num.length; j++){
                if(low > num[j]){
                    low = num[j];
                    index = j;
                }                
            }

Comment: @Marvin I added an index updater in the nested for loop ' index = j ;` Sorry I don't know how to format code in the comments.

Comment: @downshift I did and it just showed backticks as seen above

Comment: If you only modify the list by swapping, you can't create duplicate elements.  your swap is broken

Comment: `num[i] = num[index]`; is replacing all numbers in the array with `num[index]`, index got set to 2 so `num[2]` is 8 hence all `8`'s in the array. Try changing the inner loop from `for(int j = (i+1); j < num.length; j++)` to `for (int j = 1; j < num.length - i; j++)`. Then you'll want to swap the numbers inside that loop using a temp variable that saves numbers being swapped. A spoiler (I know you asked *not* for the answer), this is good swap implementation: [two loops to implement the Bubble Sort](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16089042/1248974), specifically the 3-lines inside the `if` clause

Answer (score 1):

The date for this homework has been and gone, but thought I would add some step-by-step methodology.

The way I would approach this is to break it down into small steps. Each step should be a method or function.

---

### 1. The first step is to find the smallest number in the array, starting from N.

So the method for this would be:

```
private int findLowestStartingAtNth( int n ) {
    int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for( int i = n ; i < numbers.length ; i++ ) {
        if( numbers[i] < lowest ) {
            lowest = numbers[i]; 
        }
    }
    return lowest;
}
```

---

### 2. Then we need to swap two arbitrary numbers in an array.

This is quite simple:

```
private void swapNumbers( int i, int j ) {
    int temp = numbers[i];
    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
    numbers[j] = temp;
}
```

---

### 3. But if we want the output of `findLowestStartingAtNth()` to feed into the input of `swapNumbers()`, then we need to return the *index* not the number itself.

So the method from step 1. is altered to be:

```
private int findLowestStartingAtNth( int n ) {
    int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int index = n;
    for( int i = n ; i < numbers.length ; i++ ) {
        if( numbers[i] < lowest ) {
            lowest = numbers[i]; 
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

---

### 4. Let's use what we have to achieve step one

> Select the lowest number in the list and swap with the first number.

The first number is the zero-th in the array.

```
int numbers = new int[] {33, 22, 8, 59, 14, 47, 60, 27};
int found = findLowestStartingAtNth( 0 );
swapNumbers(0, found);
```

---

### 5. We have a pattern. Start checking from 1st, swap with 1st. Start checking from 2nd, swap with 2nd. Start checking with X, swap with X.

So let's wrap this pattern in a further method:

```
private int[] numbers = new int[] {33, 22, 8, 59, 14, 47, 60, 27};
private void sort() {
    for( int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++ ) {
        int j = findLowestStartingAtNth( i );
        swapNumbers(i, j);
    }
}
```

---

### 6. Finally, wrap it in a class, and trigger it from `main()` method. See how clear the code is because it is broken into small steps.

The entire resulting class would be:

```
public class Method1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Method1 m = new Method1();
        m.numbers = new int[] {33, 22, 8, 59, 14, 47, 60, 27};
        m.sort();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(m.numbers));
    }

    private int[] numbers;

    private int findLowestStartingAtNth( int n ) {
        int lowest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int index = n;
        for( int i = n ; i < numbers.length ; i++ ) {
            if( numbers[i] < lowest ) {
                lowest = numbers[i]; 
                index = i;
            }
        }
        return index;
    }

    private void swapNumbers( int i, int j ) {
        int temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[j];
        numbers[j] = temp;
    }

    private void sort() {
        for( int i = 0 ; i < numbers.length ; i++ ) {
            int j = findLowestStartingAtNth( i );
            swapNumbers(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also worth to mention that this algorithm is called [*Selection sort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) for both educational purposes and indexing the page.