# My java program won't run properly i want it to input several numbers into an array and put the into another array in order from lowest to highest

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to make a program in java that takes user input of several numbes and  displays them to the screen in order from the highest to lowest 
But it wont work and i don't know why.

Thanks in advance
Note (this my firs time posting anything here)

```java
public class project {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] arr1 = new int[5];
        int arr2[] = new int[5];
        System.out.println("enter 5 numbers");

        for (int i=0; i<=4; i++){
            int Uinput = input.nextInt();
            arr1[i] = Uinput;
        }

        for(int b = 0; b <= 4; b++){
            for (int a = 0; a <=100;a++){
                for(int j = 0; j <=4; j++){
                    if ( a== arr1[j]){
                        arr2[b]=arr1[j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(arr2 [0]);
        System.out.println(arr2 [1]);
        System.out.println(arr2 [2]);
        System.out.println(arr2 [3]);
        System.out.println(arr2 [4]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: _"It won't work"_ - In what way?  Does it fail to compile?  Does it run but give you the wrong output?  If so, what input are you using, what is the expected output, and what is the actual output?

Comment: Also, please format so the indentation is correct, might be easier to see issue too.

Comment: I'd also suggest writing an actual sort algorithm; the logic of the three loops seems suspect. See [here for a simple bubble sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16089042/1277259)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your loops is that you are continuing with the comparison even after you have set your element in arr2. That is why they all end up as the highest number.
You only want to set each element once. You could try and put breaks into each for loop, but i the easier solution would be;

```
int b = 0;
while(b < 5) {
    for (int a = 0; a <=100;a++){
        for(int j = 0; j <=4; j++){
            if (a == arr1[j]){
                arr2[b]=arr1[j];
                b++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By incrementing b every time you set the element, you are making sure each element is only set once.

This said, KevinO is correct and there are other better ways to sort the numbers (for example, your current code can't handle numbers greater than 100). I would recommend checking out the link